# Finding substring in a string using Java

Tags: java, substring

I found this answer online but I am unable to understand what these following lines of code do in the full code:

```
if (haystackLen - i + 1 < needleLen)
            return null;
```

Find the full code below:

```
  public String strStr(String haystack, String needle) {

        int needleLen = needle.length();
        int haystackLen = haystack.length();

        if (needleLen == haystackLen && needleLen == 0)
            return "";

        if (needleLen == 0)
            return haystack;

        for (int i = 0; i < haystackLen; i++) {
            // make sure in boundary of needle
            if (haystackLen - i + 1 < needleLen)
                return null;

            int k = i;
            int j = 0;

            while (j < needleLen && k < haystackLen && needle.charAt(j) == haystack.charAt(k)) {
                j++;
                k++;
                if (j == needleLen)
                    return haystack.substring(i);
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: if second argument length is greater than as `first+1` it should return null because second string can not be substring of first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically Your code is checking second String is existing(exactly) in first String then you are returning First String.

as:

```
haystack="indian";
needle="india";
```

then output will be "indian"

and if

```
haystack="indian";
needle="indian";
```

then output will be "indian".

and if

```
haystack="india";

needle="indian";
```

then output will be "null".

which is your confusion.

```
 if (haystackLen - i + 1 < needleLen)
     return null;
```

if second String length is greater than First one and First String is matched till current index in second String it is returning null; that means second String is not subString of first one.

Comment: Why are we checking for every value of i ? Why cant we just compare the lengths of both strings directly?

Comment: @Jasdeep if you are giving input as "jhon" and "smith" then also it will return "null" because both are not matching even one character from starting.

Comment: oh ok Now i got it ... Thanks Prashant

Answer (score 0):

```
if (haystackLen - i + 1 < needleLen)
            return null;
```

So you are iterating over `haystack` and the checking for `needle` in it. At each iteration

```
haystackLen - i + 1
```

gives the length of String in the haystack  that is left to be parsed and when this is less that `needleLen` that you intent to find you are just returning null as you are sure further iteration are of no use.